# Logging query execution time in Eclipselink

Tags: eclipselink

I'd like to configure EclipseLink to log executed SQL queries and *query execution time*.

In `persistence.xml` I have following properties set:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true" />
```

I can see SQL queries, bound parameters, and execution timestamp. But not the execution time.

Here is the example of messages I see in log:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-07-14 17:22:40.114--Connection(1201360998)--SELECT ID, a, b, c FROM  my_table WHERE (id = ?)
    bind => [4]
```

It there any way how to get this information to logs?

Comment: have you seen https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Performance_Monitoring_and_Profiling/Performance_Profiling ?

Comment: I've seen EclipseLink Profiler but it does not seem to be what I'm looking for. I'd like to have basic SQL query logging, so I can see queries together with other logs, I assume I could simply take logged queries and analyze them together with used parameters. 

EclipseLink Profiler seems to be the best tool available - maybe even better than simple logging, but it is not what I'm looking for right now.